# Android Room LiveData Observer not updating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView` in it. I use a `ViewModel` to hold the `LiveData` to show from a Room database and try to update the `RecyclerView` by observing the data in the `ViewModel`. But the `Observer` only ever gets called once when I open the fragment. I update the Room databse from a different `Fragment` than the `Observer` is on.

**Wheter I add a new `Event` or delete or update one, the `Observer` never gets called! How can I get the `Observer` to be called properly? Where is my mistake?**

### Fragment

The code in `onViewCreated` does not work in `onCreate`, it return null on the line `val recyclerview = upcoming_recycler`.
You also see at the end of `onViewCreated` where I open a new fragment, from which the database gets updated. Note that the `UpcomingFragment` is in a different `FragmentLayout` than the `EventEditFragment`!

```
class UpcomingFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_upcoming) {

    private val clubDb by lazy {
        ClubDatabase.getClubDatabase(requireContext().applicationContext)
    }

    private val eventAdapter = EventAdapter(null, this)

    private val upcomingViewModel: UpcomingViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val recyclerView = upcoming_recycler
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        upcomingViewModel.eventsToShow.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { events ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Live data changed in upcomingfragment!!!")
            eventAdapter.setData(events.toTypedArray())
        })

        recyclerView.adapter = eventAdapter

        // add a new Event
        upcoming_fab.setOnClickListener {
            parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment_layout_overlay, EventEditFragment())
                .addToBackStack(EVENT_EDIT_FRAGMENT)
                .commit()
        }
        // and more stuff...
    }
    //the rest of the class
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class UpcomingViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
    val eventsToShow: LiveData<List<Event>>

    init {
        val roundToDay = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy", Locale.GERMAN)
        var today = Date()
        today = roundToDay.parse(roundToDay.format(today))!!
        val tomorrow = Date(today.time + 86400000L)
        eventsToShow = ClubDatabase.getClubDatabase(application.applicationContext).clubDao()
            .getEventsByClubIdAfterDate(CURRENT_CLUB_ID, tomorrow)
    }
}
```

### EventAdapter

```
class EventAdapter(
    private var dataSet: Array<Event>?,
    private val onEventItemClickListener: OnEventItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.EventViewHolder>() {

    class EventViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EventViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.event_item_layout, parent, false)
        return EventViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EventViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // show the item & add onEventItemClickListener for updating
    }

    fun setData(new: Array<Event>) {
        this.dataSet = new
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet?.size ?: 0
    }
}
```

### Database

```
@Database(
entities = [Event::class, Member::class, RequiredMembersForEvents::class, AttendedMembersForEvents::class],
version = 9,
exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ClubDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun clubDao(): ClubDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ClubDatabase? = null

        fun getClubDatabase(context: Context): ClubDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = INSTANCE
                return if (instance != null) {
                    instance
                } else {
                    Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ClubDatabase::class.java,
                        "club-db"
                    )
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### DAO

```
@Dao
interface ClubDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubId = :clubId AND dateTimeFrom > :date ORDER BY dateTimeFrom ASC")
    fun getEventsByClubIdAfterDate(clubId: String, date: Date): LiveData<List<Event>>

    // the rest of the DAO
}
```

Comment: Am I right that your steps to reproduce problem: 1. Open fragment UpcomingFragment, message from observe is in logcat. 2. Press FAB, open fragment EventEditFragment, edit events, press "Back". 3. Come back to fragment UpcomingFragment, there is no message from observe in logcat. 4. Close fragment UpcomingFragment, then open it again - and message from observe is in logcat. Right?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov Yes, this is how it works! The UpcomingFragment is in a different FragmentLayout than the EventEditFragment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your database singleton implementation, since variable INSTANCE there - is always null. You should set it at first time when you've got the instance of the class. Otherwise your app has a deal with different instances of your Database class.

Probably that causes a problem, when though some changes were made to database, but LiveData's observer for these changes was not triggered.